# Adding context to existing http handler function

Tags: go

I have to following setup. I have a mux HTTP server to which I want to add contexts to improve resilience.

```
srv := http.Server{
    Addr:         ":" + _operatorPortStr,
    WriteTimeout: 8 * time.Second,
    Handler:      http.TimeoutHandler(router, 5*time.Second, "Timeout!\n"),
}
srv.ListenAndServe()
```

I now have my handler function which I want to terminate if the HTTP requests reaches its timeout.

```
func Deploy(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

loadConfigs()

calltos3()

updateResource()

}
```

The main issue is that its not possible to pass the context to each function because they are very high level. So what is a correct way to add context to the handler to terminate the request after a timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeout handler sets the context in the request. You can use the request context to check if request timed out:

```
func Deploy(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   ...
   select {
      case <-r.Context().Done():
         // Timed out
      default:
   }
   ...
}
```